# .click event (jQuery) for <li> element in dropdown menu (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I've the following drop down menu:

```html
<span class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Toggle</button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li id="one">One</li>
      <li id="two">Two</li>
   </ul>
</span>
```

I would like to use the `.click` event of jQuery to check if the first item is being clicked:

```js
$(function () {
   $("#one").click(function() {
      alert("Alert!");
   });
});
```

Unfortunately that's not working.
**When the list item is NOT in the dropdown menu it works perfectly.**

Thanks for any support in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ogkychht/1/ - works for me

Comment: I don't see why it would not work. Maybe you can give us more HTML and JS. Perhaps make a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: What exactly you wanna achieve? It works perfectly! There could be some other JavaScript of CSS that might be interfering with this?

Comment: Do you load the entries dynamical? You should never use `id` with dynamic loaded content. Use something like this: `$('.dropdown-menu li:first').click( ... )'`

Comment: Finally I've found the solution. I'm using Bootstrap's responsive columns with a breakpoint for mobile devices. The dropdown menu is only visible in the mobile version. The desktop version shows the elements as plain text. Because of that the span-id exists twice. Now I'm using a class. That works!

Answer (score -1):

Just `Copy` and Check, its `Working`..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#one").click(function(){
            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Toggle</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li id="one">One</li>
            <li id="two">Two</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/t3ehq7h7/3/)